# WebRTC Native API for IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5, webrtc

I want to develop Iphone Native video chat app using WebRTC(Not browser). Main feature is Iphone user can able to call Desktop web browser. Any way?(please without third party API)

Comment: Yes, it is possible by using the native webrtc api or writing your own.

Answer (score 3):

- First, this is helpful tutorial http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/ that help you build and run AppRTCDemo on iOS simulators and devices.
- Second, download and run my [AppRTCDemo](https://github.com/ledinhphuong/AppRTCDemo) if you cannot build AppRTCDemo by you own.

Comment: The "How to..." article, republished elsewhere, but this link actually works: https://blog.csdn.net/Templar1000/article/details/22510703